# how to minimize STL file after loading to the viewport 3D of HELIX in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, helix-3d-toolkit, viewport3d

Hello I made an application through which user can import an STL file, I have made it as WPF application and trying to open the file using Helix 3D tool kit but the problem is when I'm trying to open my STL file the image gets enlarged and I'm unable to minimize its size /keep it fit in the center. enter code here
Please find the attached code I have written for opening STL file.
**MainWindow.XAML//imported helix 3d toolkit for opening STL files**

helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="viewPort3d" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True"  CoordinateSystemHeight="100"  Margin="0,50,0,0"

**MainWindow.XAML,cs File//**
on button click I'm importing the STL file.

```
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            FileNameTextBox.Text = filename;                
            ModelVisual3D device3D = new ModelVisual3D();             
            device3D.Content = Display3d(filename );              
            viewPort3d.Children.Add(device3D);  //here iam loading the stl file to the   helix:HelixViewport3D
```

please find the below images for better understanding

**my output** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpoBS.png)

**Desired Output**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2moB.png)

can you please help me how to minimize the STL file size after loading to the viewport3D.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using `viewPort3d.ZoomExtents();` should work.

Comment: thanks redscorp...it worked for me in the application.